# StrongLoop: POST access not being blocked

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using ACL rules to block all types of accesses from all the users. It is working for GET access but it is NOT working for POST accesses.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here is the code and sample results:

**/common/models/client.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "plural": "clients",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**GET access error (working as expected, it is blocked):**

*CURL*

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "http://localserver:8080/api/quants"
```

*RESPONSE*

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at ...
  }
}
```

**POST error, access didnt get blocked. Not working.**

*CURL:*

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"email\": \"test@email.com\",
  \"password\": \"abcd1234\"
}
" "http://localserver:8080/api/clients"
```

*RESPONSE*

```
{
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "id": "46b258078da5dtg1ji5809ww"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before suggesting solutions, I'll try to explain what's the cause of 'create' (POST) method to not be denied.

Your `client` model is a sub-model of Loopback's `User` built in model.

Two important things to keep in mind in this case:

1. ACL's defined in a sub-model are **not overriding the base class ACL's**, [but merged to them](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/acl.js#L355).
2. When a request is checked against ACLs, Loopback's algorithm gives the **closer** match higher weight. closer match in this specific case is **a more specific ACL definition**. (reference [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/iSE1xa2vXBI))

Now, Loopback's `User` model [contains the following ACL](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L42-L47):

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "create"
}
```

Your defined ACL

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
  // no specific property
}
```

**is less specific**, hence not chosen by the algorithm.

---

In order to solve the issue, you can:

1. Add specific ACL for denying creation:

   ```
   {
     "principalType": "ROLE",
     "principalId": "$everyone",
     "permission": "DENY",
     "property": "create"
   }
   ```
2. Remove the ACL allowing to create from the base `User` model (**very bad solution, but works**)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Reuven. I picked solution 1), to add specific ACL rule in my client model which is the best solution.